# Animating the constant in nslayoutconstraint - ambiguous layout

Tags: ios

Looking at people's examples, I'd think that animating the NSLayoutConstraint.constant in one direction would be pretty straight forward.  I keep getting ambiguous layout and I'm not sure why.  I have a label that I have these constraints set up for in viewDidLoad.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *xConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_locationLabel
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:20];

    [self.view addConstraint:xConstraint];
    NSLayoutConstraint *yConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_locationLabel
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:20];
    [self.view addConstraint:yConstraint];
    self.locationLabelYConstraint = yConstraint;
```

Then I just want to move the label on a tap in the Y direction.  In my gesture recognizer method:

```
if (_locationLabelYConstraint.constant == 20.0) {
    _locationLabelYConstraint.constant = 30.0;
} else {
    _locationLabelYConstraint.constant = 20.0;
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:10 options:0 animations:^{
    self.isLocationLabelOnScreen = NO;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}completion:nil];
```

The label moves as I expect, but I immediately get ambiguous layout to the console.

```
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0xc0a73b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(20)-[UILabel:0xc0a4400]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xc0a65b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc0a6d90 V:|-(30)-[UILabel:0xc0a4400]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xc0a65b0 )>"
```

For animating the constant value of nslayoutconstraint, don't I just update the constant value, and call layoutIfNeeded in the animation block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because Interface Builder is generating constraints that are conflicting with yours.

It's easier to create the constraints yourself on Interface Builder and reference them programmatically with outlets.

Comment: But doesn't `[_locationLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` opt me out of IB generated constraints?

Comment: No, that's when you have a .xib or storyboard without auto-layout active and don't want iOS to translate the autoresizing masks to constraints automatically on that particular view.

Comment: If I didn't use an outlet though, how would I get it to work by just updating the constant in the constraint?

Comment: I guess you could search for the constraint you want inside the `-constraints` property of the view.